# How do I show classes of two different variants with two possible values in a class diagram?

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-diagram, class-design

I have an entity `Question` (abstract) in my project. It can be asked in English or Russian. In addition, it can be asked by a student or a non-student. So,I'm looking for the perfect way to show it in my class diagram.

The only way I see, is to create four different classes (English-Student, English-NonStudent, NonEnglish-Student, NonEnglish-NonStudent). I guess, it will be the most efficient way to store them in different tables (different classes in class diagram).

What are the drawbacks of this approach?  Would there be a better design?

Answer (score 2):

### Limitation of the current design

Your current design ignores the fact that questions share some common features and behaviors, regardless of who asks in which language:

- this introduces redundancy in the design and the implementation that will make maintenance less efficient and more error prone. Suppose for example that you want to add to the question some voting score like on StackOverflow:  you would have to introduce your change in every variant of `Question`.  If you would forget one of it in your revision, the code would break in some specific cases (usually the one that was not tested well).
- the design is not compliant with the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle):  if you would add other languages, e.g. Ukrainian and French, your design would get broken and you'll have to add lots more classes and modify all the classes/code that use/work with questions.

### How to improve?

First, does the language or the status of the author (student vs. non-student lead to any change in the behavior of the question?

If no, the simplest is to add a property `language` to the class `Question`.  In the same spirit, you'd add an [`«enumeration»`](https://www.softwareideas.net/class-diagram-enum) to identify the kind of author (unless the question is not already associated with an `Author` that provides similar information).

If there would indeed be different behaviors, or if depending on the combination, you'd need some additional properties, then you could use inheritance. But you'd quickly end-up in a very deep class hierarchy or multiple inheritance.

A better alternative could be to prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):  typically using a [strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy) for the language and the author category; although I could imagine that you should consider [decorator pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator) if a student question would for example bear more information than a non-student one.

Comment: Hmm. Questions (often) depend on the language (and culture). So asking a question in English is different from asking in Russian (supposed it's not a fact question like _When was Caesar murdered?_). It depends on the requirements (as so often).

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed,  the question depends on language and culture. But I suspect it's probably, it's more about expressing the question (e.g. question mark at the end without space in English; reverse question mark at the beginning, and question mark at the end for Spanish, etc..), which could be dealt with by exporting the questing text in a language specific text class (composition).  Language could also influence the workflow of the question (who can answer, in which list to display it, etc...), a certain number of things that could simply be obtained by associating the question with a langu

Comment: ...language.  My main point here is exactly that:  it depends on the requirements if there is a need to distinguish language and origin at class level at all,  and if yes,  to present alternatives with the relevant constraints (i.e.  the combinatorial explosion of the combination make it difficult to manage via inheritance).

Comment: @qwerty_so Now I assumed that it was not about modelling an AI system that interprets questions and assign them to mod, sentiments, or answers it.  This would be much more delicate to model.  By the way, I wonder why we didn't get question about AI and ML modelling in UML, so far ;-)

Comment: Always the same thing. Once you start thinking about a problem lots of questions bubble up from the ground. So the anser to _better design_ is "it depends".